# Can you help with the spaces generated?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be a $n \times n$ matrix and $[A_{1},...,A_{n}]$ The columns of the matrix,

my question is:

Why if $Ax=b$ then $A^{T}b\in Span [A_ {1}, ..., A_ {n}]$?

Where x is any vector of length n

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is x here?

Comment: @Bitwise: any vector of length $m$

Comment: @Bitwise is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A^Tb$ is a vector in the row space of $A$. Since $A$ is square, row space = column space, so $A^Tb$ is also a vector in the column space of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  it might be enlightening to write it out by components for $A$ being $1 \times 2$ and again $2 \times 1$

Comment: What if the matrix is square, ie n times n?

Comment: @MiguelMoraLuna:  it works the same for a square matrix.